# Pressure in a spirometer?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQg04.jpg

so I have this [spirometer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spirometer) here to find out the volume of exhaled air, yet The procedure of exhaling through the tube gives me the question of how does the water move into the other rubber tubing explained  using physics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you exhale, the pressure of the gas above the liquid increases. This pushes liquid up the tube - if you keep the exit of the tube at roughly the same height as the liquid level ($h$ in my diagram), you don't need very much pressure differential to move the liquid. The most pressure you would need is that which pushes the liquid to the top of the tube, height $H$.

When the height difference is $h$, the pressure difference needed is $\rho g h$ where $\rho$ is the density of the liquid, and $g$ the acceleration of gravity. An easy rule of thumb is that 10 m column of water produces 1 atm ($10^5~\rm{Pa}$) of pressure; so if you can keep things down to a few cm height difference, you need just a few 100 Pa of pressure difference between the inside ($P_{int}$) and the outside ($P_{ext}$). Most people have no problem doing that.

[image]